Embedded LWC in Screen Flow causes Error on Finished Flow Interview
I have a LWC embedded in a screen flow, and it works as intended. But whenever I click the finish button on the screen flow component I get prompted an error. The error can be found here and the screen flow can be seen here. This error occurs when a debug the flow and when I invoke the flow from a lightning page


Furthermore, I have included the stack trace from chrome dev tools which can be found here:

If anyone has encountered this error before or know a solution please let me know. Also, here is some more context on how my LWC works

I invoke the getRecord uiRecordAPI and wire it in my code. It contains a recordId parameter passed into from the flow
I did not implement disconnectedCallback. Could this be the issue? If so, what do I do.

Other Questions

From the screen flow, is there a way to catch the exception and not show the error to the user similar to a try/catch?


Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.
